# Не отображается аватар в header-е сайта

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Поменял аватар недавно на [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXfvc.jpg). Теперь в header-е отображается его половина, или что это такое:

[image]

В других местах отображается нормально. Думал проблема рендеринга и увеличил/уменьшил размеры сайта - без изменений.

Comment: Закешировался криво. Почисть кэш. Впрочем, тогда куча фейсбучных аватарок пропадёт.

Comment: @Qwertiy работает, спасибо.